# PostgreSQL - Add CONSTRAINT UNIQUE and do not validate exisiting data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a small problem with adding new `CONSTRAINT` to my table.
I want to add a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` and do not validate existing data in my table.

I have some duplicates in existing data and I want to leave it like it is.

I wrote a query:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl1 
   ADD CONSTRAINT unique_const UNIQUE (fld1, fld2) NOT VALID;
```

But it's not working, I got an error:

> `UNIQUE constraints cannot be marked NOT VALID`

I also tried removing all `TRIGGERS`:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl1 DISABLE TRIGGER all;
ALTER TABLE tbl1 ADD CONSTRAINT unique_const UNIQUE (fld1, fld2);
ALTER TABLE tbl1 ENABLE TRIGGER all;
```

But it also does not work.

Does anyone know how to add a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` without validating existing rows?

Answer (score 2):

If you can specifically identify those lines which should be ignored for the constraint, you could add a partial unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON table (columns) WHERE some_condition;
```

If you don't have an existing direct condition, you may need to add a column to the table to identify those lines that should be ignored (with an appropriate default so that new lines are counted).

Not sure if there's an equivalent `ALTER TABLE` syntax.

Comment: is it ok if we leave the old data without intention to correct it? so we never remove the condition from our index

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation of PostgreSQL 9.6](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altertable.html), unfortunately the `NOT VALID` option is currently only allowed with foreign key and `CHECK` constraints.
[This StackOverflow thread here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66840/add-not-null-constraint-to-large-table-without-table-scan) might be related and provide ideas/basic approaches for an alternative solution, although it's from 2014.

Comment: This is also true for 9.5 and 9.6

Comment: Thank you very much. Edited that. :)